# How to get hashmap particular key value in mule dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am new for mule and i am trying to fetch below hashmap memberId value in dataweave but below code getting compile time error, Can some one help me to how do we fetch memebrId value alone from below hasmap?.

### hashmap:

```
{
  "0":{
    "key":"auth",
    "value":true
  },
  "1":{
    "key":"memebrId",
    "value":"ESC0099123"
  },
  "2":{
    "key":"name",
    "value":"Ramakrishna"
  }
}
```

### Code which I tried:

(payload pluck $ filter ($.key == "memebrId"))[0].value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take all values of the object as an array using `valuesOf`, and then filter the array to get the object containing `memberId` which will give you an array of single object related to memberId.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
valuesOf(payload)[?($.key == 'memebrId')][0].value
```

The `[?($.key == 'memebrId')]` part is an alternative selector to `filter` you can use to shorten the overall expression, and avoid some extra braces. Since you are new to this, I will give the expanded version

```js
(valuesOf(payload) filter ((item) -> item.key == 'memebrId'))[0].value
```

[image: image from https://developer.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave/]

Comment: let me try and let you know

Comment: Hi its not working

Comment: Its saying there is field with an expression error

Comment: It is working for me, I used the hashmap that you provided as payload. Maybe the payload that you are using is different. I have updated my answer with the ss of input I am using. Can you share the error that you are getting?

Comment: Hi Harshank i just want to store memberId key value alone in variable

Comment: I don't need entire object which is equals to memberId

Comment: hope your understand wat i am excepecting

Comment: @Krish Yeah, I updated the expression. Check it now

Comment: You would need to have .value instead of key in your expanded option.

Comment: Not sure how its working your side

Comment: my paload having linkedHashmap is that is reason for this issue?

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 3):

you could do something like this

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload pluck $ filter ($.key == "memebrId"))[0].value
```

[image]

Comment: i am still getting error while i am running

Comment: dont know reason how come its working your end